# What's the right material (kind of caulk?) to seal where a Bilco doorframe touches my house?

Tags: basement, door-frame, caulking

My house has a fairly standard bulkhead with a Bilco door for entering the basement. Recently a leak has developed and water drips in where the metal frame touches the house. There's some old decaying caulk there now, and I can see daylight through it.

What's the best material, and possible some pointers on technique, for repairing this?

Comment: Remove the old, bad caulk, clean surfaces, replace with new fresh exterior-grade caulk?  I like poly rather than silicone here.

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @Huesmann. Also, this is an _excellent_ time to inspect the door & frame to ensure there's no rust. If it's starting to rust, there's little hope of having a long term fix that doesn't involve getting rid of the rust.